Disable PowerOff shortcut on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1. When I press Fn + Shift simultaneously, a pop-up to shut down my computer appears. I tried to disable the shortcut from setting, but the key combination itself is recognized as 'PowerOff' instead of 'Fn + Shift'. Are there any ways to disable this, or bind this key combination for nothing?

The pop-up still shows up when I bind this shortcut for the command ':', however it didn't show up when I bound it to 'Show Activity Screen'. What is the difference?

did you try Settings > Power > General and change the dropdown to Nothing?

@graham It worked. Thank you so much!! Also do you have any ideas why my computer recognize 'Fn + Shift' as the power button? Anyways, your answer helped me so much :)

I've posted that as an answer in case anyone else has a similar issue. You might wish to accept it by clicking on the grey tick so that it comes up in searches. Thanks for the feedback

my English (UK) kbd also has a Fn key next to AltGr but it doesn't perform the action you reported.

Settings > Power > General then set Power Button Behavior to Nothing.
The OP reports that this fixed the issue.
